# matlab/octave plot a mesh

Tags: matlab, octave

```
t=0:0.01:2;
alpha=linspace(0, 1, 41);
r=linspace(0,1,41);
[aa,rr] = meshgrid(alpha,r);
```

At each point of (aa, rr), for each t there is a value t^aa+rr^2, then those values are summed up:

```
sum = (t1^aa+rr^2) + (t2^aa+rr^2) + ...
```

Thus for each point of (aa,rr), there is a number of sum. How do you plot that mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `t` into the third dimension to generate all triples of `aa`, `rr` and `t` via [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), and then [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) over that dimension to get the desired result:

```
t3 = reshape(t, 1, 1, []);
s = sum(t3.^aa + rr.^2, 3);
mesh(aa, rr, s)
```

In your example, this produces

[image]